# Does jQuery function have to be in the body?

Tags: jquery, execution

I am trying to setup an animated menu based off an older jQuery menu.  The older version, the function was put directly into the body along with the jQuery version reference link.  The problem I had was, that setup conflicts with a rotating banner I also want to put on the page.

In effect, currently they cannot both run at the same time. They are both running on different jQuery versions also.

I got some help putting the jQuery execution function into an external file however that didn't resolve the issue with the menu because the jQuery version and call has to be referenced in the body for it to work.

I have seen jQuery menus before that do not need to be put directly in the body. Or do they?  I know below is a very bad way to do it as it's inside the body of the page, plus its using an outdated version of jQuery which is why I am looking to updated it make it more solid.

```
       <body>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
          $(function() {
              $('#hn_menu > li').bind('mouseenter',function(){
                 var $elem = $(this);
                 $elem.find('img')
                 .stop(true)
                 .animate({
                    'width':'120px',
                    'height':'120px',
                    'left':'0px'
                 },400,'easeOutBack')
              .andSelf()
              .find('.hn_wrap')
              blah blah blah
             });
          });
         </body>
```

Comment: You really, really don't want to be running two separate jQuery versions.  You ought to figure out why that is the case and fix it so you can run only one jQuery version.  There is a managed way to run two versions at the same time using jQuery.noConflict() and alternative symbols for jQuery or confining one version to a particular scope, but it takes knowing what you're doing to do that properly.

Answer (score 1):

No, the script doesn't have to b in the body. As you are using the `ready` event, the script can be anywhere in the page (after the jQuery library has been loaded, of course).

Normally you would put a script in the `head` tag, not the `body` tag. Scripts are generally only put in the `body` tag if you want them to load later than other resources, or if they are not using the `ready` or `load` events so the sript has to be placed after the elements that it accesses.

(Note that the code that you posted is missing the `script` tag around the script, so it would just display it in the page.)

Comment: Thanks Guffa, yes I was just putting that in there as an example. I was just reading on the jQuery site that perhaps the reason why this wont work from the head section of the page is because I need the getElelmentByID().  Am I on the right path with this?

Comment: What I am understanding is that when I put the script reference in the body, it is nulling or destroying the functionality of my banner rotator which is running on a newer version (that script is in the head).  Whats more difficult is that they are both setup completely different. I have been reading the noConflict however that wont work because again, these two plugins are setup completely different.

Comment: @JeremyWinslow: No, as the code runs in an event handler for the `ready` event, all elements are already loaded when the code runs. It doesn't matter that you bind the event before the elements are loaded, as the event is triggered after all elements are loaded.

Comment: @JeremyWinslow: Using different versions of jQuery with scripts that uses events is complicated, because when the `load` and `ready` events are triggered, only one version of jQuery is referred to by the `jQuery` and `$` identifiers, so both scripts would use the same version anyway. You would need to rewrite one script to use a different identifier for its own version of jQuery.

Comment: I see.. thanks again Guffa.  I am TRYING (Im not a js guy) to recode the menu as it seems easier however I cannot find any documentation on how to upgrade this old version to another old version.  I though maybe perhaps recode them both to the newest version 1.9.1 but I am already having trouble making heads of tails of one of this methods major features .andSelft() I replaced this with .addBack() and put the update 1.9.1 jQuery version in the body instead, I cannot get this to work. I am think I am going to have to pick at it bit by bit and see if I can get some reaction.

Comment: @JeremyWinslow: Updating one or both scripts to a newer version sounds like the easist road. There should be some tips on how to replace deprecated or removed methods in the documentation, like how the `andSelf` documentation describes that it is an alias for `addBack`.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can put it anywhere between the `<script type="text/javascript"> </script>` tags. Before that, you have to load jQuery, if you are using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery v1.9.1 works with all previous versions of jQuery regardless of what methods they claim are deprecated. You do not even need the migration guide script.

For example, this script has

```
   .andSelf()
```

jQuery said that was replaced with

```
    .addBack(optional param)
```

it might have been replaced but addSelf() still works with the new 1.9.1

Comment: No, some methods and objects are removed in 1.9.1. The `browser` object for example was removed in version 1.9. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/